# Using @Grab in Jenkins pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In my Jenkins build, I am using the [pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin).

Within it, I am making a REST call.

For that call, I needed to use:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )
```

However, for this I am getting the error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsExcepti‌​on: startup failed: General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7: not found]
```

So how can I use `@Grab` in the Jenkins pipeline plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The exception occurs because somehow grapes isn't finding httpclient 4.2.1 so add http client 4.2.6 and it should work for you.

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )

@Grab('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6')
```